# Nexus: SSL issue logging into NPM repository behind Nginx proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, npm, nexus

I have Nexus 3 set up behind an Nginx proxy. A private root CA was set up to issue certs for the internal network and this all works fine to securely load the nexus website.

I created a private NPM repository and now I'm trying to login with NPM. Initially when I tried to login I got the error `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`. This seemed to be related to the fact that NPM didn't know about the root CA that issued the Nexus cert (there is no intermediate CA in this case). So I specified the CA certificate in the NPM configuration with

`npm config set cafile rootCA.pem`

Now when I try to login with NPM I get the error `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this issue is more so with npm, and more more so with nodejs than it is with Nexus Repository (in fact I think Nexus Repository is innocent in the case of npm and private ssl cert versus Nexus Repository). I'm relatively sure it's related to this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742 , so you can first try another version of node where this is fixed (since npm is using a node libary, after all), or you can alternatively try

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

"so says Snoop Dogg".

The latter is a hack, for sure.